# How can I retrieve all Objects in a List that have certain attributes?

Tags: java, list, object

For example, I've created a list of "Incidents" from a service portal:

```
List<Incident> incidentObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < incidentNumberList.size(); i++) {
    Incident incident = new Incident();
    incident.setIncidentNumber(incidentNumberList.get(i));
    incident.setSummary(summaryList.get(i));
    incident.setRequestId(requestIdList.get(i));
    incident.setPriority(priorityList.get(i));
    incident.setLastModifiedDate(lastModifiedDateList.get(i));
    incidentObjectList.add(incident);
}
System.out.println("Incident Object List" + incidentObjectList);
```

Each Incident has several attributes, but I want only to create a new list from that original List composed of Incident Objects with Priority `Low`. In this case, `incident.getPriority()` will return the String `Low` for all Objects in the new List.

```
String[] dataGreenArray = incidentObjectList.get();
retrieveTickets(dataGreenArray, listViewGreen);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the `incidentObjectList` and check the priority of each element.

```
for (Incident incident: incidentObjectList)
{
    if (incident.getPriority().equals("Low")
        desiredList.add(incident);         // or whatever you want to do
}
```

This is a very basic solution, but unless you are specifically looking for something else, it should work. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8

```
List<Incident> list = incidentObjectList.stream()
                                        .filter(e->e.getPriorty().equals("Low"))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```